# how to make CGFloat value shorter when display in NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgfloat

I am new to objective-c. I want to display shorter CGFloat value in NSString. I know in C its easy. But i don't know how to do that in Objective-c.
For example,

```
 CGFloat value = 0.333333;
 NSLog(@"%f%%",value*100);
```

It will display 33.3333%. But i want to make it 33.33%. How can i do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CGFloat value = 0.333333;
NSLog(@"%.2f%%",value*100);
```

Will result in `33.33%` in the log.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) is the relevant section from Apple's docs. The Objective-C format specifiers very closely follow (or might even be the same as) those you might know from C. `NSLog()` automatically accepts format specifiers. To do this with any `NSString`, use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myString", arg1, arg2..]`.

Comment: @chancy This is fine for internal use but if you ever need to format such a value for display to the user, do not do this. Instead, use NSNumberFormatter so the number is properly formatted based on the user's locale.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want, you can use `printf()` like in C.

Comment: Actually i want to display in nsstring. Now i know how to do that. Thanks.